# How to display newly added tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

I am using python3 tkinter. I am trying to update a table to dynamically add new lines of Entry widgets.
The layout is as follows:

1. frame_canvas include a canvas and a scrollbar
2. frame_entries is on the canvas, showing 5x7 windows only
3. frame_entries holds a 2-dimensional Entry table

I'd like to dynamically add new rows on the Entry table, thus, adding new Entry rows on frame_entries frame.
The problem now is that the addition of these new widgets won't update the widgets display, it would only replace the last row of Entry table on the screen. (data was updated correctly on the background, just the problem of display update)

I tried to call canvas.update() and frame_entries.update() but no use. Scrollbar doesn't reflect the updated Entry table either.

I updated the code snippet so you can download and try.

```
import tkinter as tk

total_columns = 5
total_rows = 18
tbl = []

def add_row_table():
    global total_rows

    new_row: list[Entry] = [tk.Entry() for _ in range(total_columns)]
    for j in range(total_columns):
        new_row[j] = tk.Entry(frame_entries, width=20)
        new_row[j].grid(row=total_rows, column=j, sticky="news")
        new_row[j].insert(tk.END, total_rows)
    total_rows += 1

    # canvas.update_idletasks()
    # frame_entries.update_idletasks()
    tbl.append(new_row)

root = tk.Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame_main = tk.Frame(root, bg="gray")
frame_main.grid(sticky='news')

button2 = tk.Button(frame_main, text="Add Row", fg="green", command=add_row_table)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(5, 0), sticky='nw')

frame_canvas = tk.Frame(frame_main)
frame_canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5, 0), sticky='nw')
frame_canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# Set grid_propagate to False to allow table resizing later
frame_canvas.grid_propagate(False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame_canvas, bg="yellow")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

vsb = tk.Scrollbar(frame_canvas, orient="vertical",         command=canvas.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

frame_entries = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="blue")
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_entries, anchor='nw')

for i in range(total_rows):
    line = [tk.Entry() for j in range(total_columns)]
    for j in range(total_columns):
        line[j] = tk.Entry(frame_entries, width=20)
        line[j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="news")
        line[j].insert(tk.END, i)

    tbl.append(line)

frame_entries.update_idletasks()

columns_width = sum([tbl[0][j].winfo_width() for j in range(total_columns)])
rows_height = sum([tbl[i][0].winfo_height() for i in range(5)])
frame_canvas.config(width=columns_width + vsb.winfo_width(),
                height=rows_height+150)

canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are `tables`, `entry_line` and `line`?  You haven't call any layout function on the newly created entries, so they will be invisible.  Better provide a [mre].

Comment: Hi, acw1668, thank you very much for suggestions. First time post here. I already updated the complete snippet

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `scrollregion` of `canvas` after adding entries to `frame_entries`:

```py
...
# function to be called whenever frame_entries is resized
def frame_entries_resized(event):
    # update canvas scrollregion
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
...
frame_entries = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="blue")
# monitor size of frame_entries
frame_entries.bind('<Configure>', frame_entries_resized)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_entries, anchor='nw')
...
```

---

Note that you have created duplicate set of entries:

```py
for i in range(total_rows):
    # initialise with entries into 'line'
    line = [tk.Entry() for j in range(total_columns)]
    # then assign new entry into 'line' again
    for j in range(total_columns):
        line[j] = tk.Entry(frame_entries, width=20)
        line[j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="news")
        line[j].insert(tk.END, i)

    tbl.append(line)
```

You can initialize `line` as list of `None` instead:

```
line = [None for j in range(total_columns)]
```

Same issue inside `add_row_table()`:

```
def add_row_table():
    global total_rows

    # should initialise new_row as list of None instead
    new_row: list[Entry] = [tk.Entry() for _ in range(total_columns)]
    for j in range(total_columns):
        new_row[j] = tk.Entry(frame_entries, width=20)
        new_row[j].grid(row=total_rows, column=j, sticky="news")
        new_row[j].insert(tk.END, total_rows)
    total_rows += 1

    # canvas.update_idletasks()
    # frame_entries.update_idletasks()
    tbl.append(new_row)
```